# sed creating ^M at end of line

Tags: sed, centos

I have a script on a centos server and I wrote the script on the server using VIM. The script is to edit a configuration file. When I check the configuration file after it has been edited, there is a ^M at the end of every line that was NOT edited. The lines that were edited are fine.

```
        cat hibernate.properties | 
    sed -i.bk \
    -e 's%\(^hibernate\.connection\.url\=ristor:jdbc:postgresql:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1/\).*%\'1$dbname'%' \
    -e 's/\(^hibernate\.connection\.username\=\).*/\'1$dbuser'/' \
    -e 's/\(^hibernate\.connection\.password\=\).*/\'1$pws'/' hibernate.properties
```

This is the code that is being used to edit the configuration file. Why is it putting ^M at the end of every line that is NOT edited?

Comment: maybe the source file itself has ^M. Use dos2unix to remove the ctrol-M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^M` being shown are probably windows-style line endings on some lines. Try to run your file through [`dos2unix`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) before running your script.

For example:

```
dos2unix hibernate.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not likely to add `\r`, it's more like that the file *had* them already, but was detected as `dos` fileformat by `vim`. Your script actually *removed* it from each line it has touched and `vim` doesn't consider the file `dos` anymore and therefore shows carriage returns that are still left in. Once you remove them (`%s/<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-M>$//` in `vim` should do), it is not likely to happen again.